# Google Charts, Setting gridlines count of barchart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

Currently I am working with the Google Charts API to generate some charts. To display the correct image I should change the gridline steps of the X-axis (values) marked with the green gridlines.

#### Current graph

[image: Image of the current graph]
<sub>(source: [jordysipkema.nl](http://jordysipkema.nl/images/so-img1.png))</sub>

#### Expected graph

[image: Image of the expected graph]
<sub>(source: [jordysipkema.nl](http://jordysipkema.nl/images/so-img2.png))</sub>

(Expected graph made by resizing the browser)

#### Setting the data

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Labels');
data.addColumn('number', 'Result value');
data.addRows([
    ["Label 1", 8.098205131],
    ["Label 2", 10.08567831],
    ["Label 3", 10.790166352],
    ["Label 4", 9.148802676],
    ["Label 5", 8.571340962]
]);
```

#### Define graph options

```
var options = {        
    title: 'Title - Value Bar Chart',
    subtitle: 'Uses: label and a value',
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    },
    height: chartHeight,
    bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    hAxis: {
        format: '#.###',
        gridlines: {
            color: '#00ff00' //Green lines for debugging purposes 
            // count: 4
        },
        ticks: [8, 9, 10, 11],
        viewWindow: {
            min: Math.floor(columnRange.min),
            max: Math.ceil(columnRange.max)
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
        color: '#ff0000', //Red lines
            count: 1
        }
    }
};
```

I've read about the `hAxis.gridlines.count` parameter in the options array. Unfortunately this doesn't change anything to the chart. In this given case, where the values range from 8 to 11, I would like to have 4 gridlines (set at 8, 9, 10 and 11).

The other approach I've tried is setting the `hAxis.ticks` parameter to `[8, 9, 10, 11]`. This didn't affect the graph either.

A working JSFiddle example to demonstrate what is going on:
[JSFiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/jordysipkema/7ko71u05/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I managed to get the expected result is by constraining the width to 600px:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Title - Value Bar Chart',
    subtitle: 'Uses: label and a value',
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    },
    width: 600,
    height: chartHeight,
    bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    hAxis: {
        format: '#.###',
        gridlines: {
            color: '#00ff00' //Green lines for debugging purposes
        },
        viewWindow: {
            min: Math.floor(columnRange.min),
            max: Math.ceil(columnRange.max)
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
            color: '#ff0000', //Red lines
            count: 1
        }
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qLpwrtmw/

Comment: Hmm, thats a bummer. Thanks for answering anyway.
I decided to pick another graph library anyway. Missing such a core feature in a graph library is quite annoying.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.. To be fair there's better chart libs out there, but I'm stuck using Google Charts in this project :(

Comment: .. and to anyone reading this, I had luck migrating from the material chart to the older column chart instead: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options .. Seems like vAxis/hAxis works there